# How to inherit from NSTokenAttachmentCell in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift (and objective-c), you cannot normally subclass NSTokenAttachmentCell. However, if I create a bridging header and define a header for NSTokenAttachmentCell, I can then subclass it in Swift.

[Here is an example of it in objective-c](https://bitbucket.org/bwalkin/bwtoolkit/src/590c12e68e7a9a35efc753ddfa2fa14217eb3da6/BWTokenAttachmentCell.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). NSTokenAttachmentCell isn't publicly available. However, if you create a header file for it, you can subclass it. You can't create header files in Swift. Other than creating one in a bridging header, is there a way to do this in Swift?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "NSTokenAttachmentCell.h"

@interface BWTokenAttachmentCell : NSTokenAttachmentCell {}
@end
```

Comment: in objective-c, `NSTokenAttachmentCell` is not private because it is declared in the .h file.

Comment: @janusfidel it's not publicly available. You have to do a class dump and generate it yourself. Would "Apple internal" be a better description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Swift system module `swift package init --type executable`. The only file in addition to the standard SPM files was the custom header file that wasn't publicly available.

I can now use the system module package as a dependency and subclass the Apple class that you can't normally subclass.

[Here is the full example.](https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/TokenExample)

`git clone https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/TokenExample && cd TokenExample && swift test`

You will see the correct inheritance

```
Success: - <TokenExample.CustomTokenAttachmentCell: 0x7fc1be803d10> #0
  - super: NSTokenAttachmentCell
    - super: NSTextAttachmentCell
      - super: NSCell
        - super: NSObject
```

I used these two guides as a reference:

[ship-c-code-with-swift-packages](https://medium.com/@Aciid/ship-c-code-with-swift-packages-using-swift-package-manager-44edcc702a45)

[importing-c-library-into-swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/12/importing-c-library-into-swift/)

Comment: Thanks for this, Joel. If I were to use such a subclass, I believe I also need to override a private a method in NSTokenFieldCell. Any chance you have a working example of the whole thing? I tried to create a separate package along the same lines for NSTokenFieldCell but it's a little too much voodoo, and I can't get it to build.

Comment: https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/NSTokenAttachmentCell @DaniloCampos I updated the readme to show how I expose the objc method to swift.

Comment: @DaniloCampos I'll try to put something together this weekend.

Comment: That readme is SUPER helpful. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: As technically sound the solution is, it should be mentioned that Apple could change its implementation of `NSTokenFieldCell` anytime, breaking this concept - this is  why hacking into undocumented parts is normally avoided.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is no, you can't inherit from private classes.

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only within a single declaration.

source: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: If I create a bridging header and either import the NSTokenAttachmentCell.h file or paste the contents on the header in the bridging header, I can subclass NSTokenAttachmentCell.

Comment: If it's not private what would you call it? It's not documented anywhere and you can't subclass it normally.

Comment: You are asking about an objective-C class in the BWToolkitFramework.. not sure how this is related to your question "How to inherit from private classes" with a swift tag ...so not sure if you are asking about how to inherit this specific objective-c class into swift without a bridging header..or a general how do you inherit from private classes. Please be clear or close this question

Comment: I'm not asking about an objective-C class in the BWToolkitFramework. I was using it as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish but done in objective-c. I'm looking to do the same thing in swift, hence the swift tag. The class I'm looking to inherit from is not publicly available, hence the "private" part.

Comment: then you can't inherit from said swift class, if it is Internal access (you can inherit from it in the same module with - class MyNewClass: ClassIwantToInherit {